# Sort version strings on bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Example content of STRINGS.txt:

```
    3.0.3
    3.0.11.2
    3.0.11.1
    3.0.11
    3.0.16
    3.0.15.1
    3.0.15
    3.0.14
    3.0.10.3
    3.0.10.2
    3.0.10.1
    3.0.13.1
    3.0.10
    3.0.13
    3.0.9
    3.0.12
    3.0.8
    3.0.7.2
    3.0.7.1
    3.0.7
    3.0.9.2
    3.0.9.1
    3.0.2
    3.0.8.1
    3.0.6.1
    3.0.6
    3.0.5
    3.0.1
    3.0.0
```

Is it possible to sort all those version strings only with bash, that the latest is on the top?

Comment: By "only bash", you mean no external tools at all (ie. no `sort`)? If you *can* use `sort`, what implementation do you have? GNU sort has a version-sort option built in.

Comment: Implement a [sort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Sorting_algorithms) with bash.

Comment: With "only bash" I  mean without extra software like Python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible, but a silly amount of work. If you have GNU sort:

```
sort -V -r <STRINGS.txt
```

...will do exactly what you're asking for.

---

Now, if you *really* mean with no external tools, then you're getting into some trouble. BlastHardcheese on Freenode's #bash IRC channel has written the following quicksort algorithm in native bash, which I've modified for readability, to factor out the `compare` function to be replacible, and to use Bash 4.3 namevars to be able to work with a configurable variable name (of course, this latter change means that a very new version of bash is required):

```
# this needs to be replaced for this particular case
compare(){
  (( $1 >= $2 ))
}

swap(){
  declare -n a=$1
  local t
  t=${a[$2]}
  a[$2]=${a[$3]}
  a[$3]=$t
}

partition(){
  declare -n a=$1
  local c p x
  p=${a[$4]}
  c=$2
  swap "$1" "$3" "$4"
  for((x=$2;x<$3;x++)); do
    if ! compare "${a[x]}" "$p"; then
      swap "$1" "$x" "$c"
      ((c++))
    fi
  done
  swap "$1" "$2" "$c"
  n=$c
}

quicksort(){
  declare -n a=$1
  (( "$2" >= "$3" )) && return
  local i n
  i=$((($2+$3)/2))
  partition "$1" "$2" "$3" "$i"
  quicksort "$1" "$2" "$((n-1))"
  quicksort "$1" "$((n+1))" "$3"
}
```

...implement your own comparison function, and this is then adoptable.

To handle only the cases you've shown here:

```
# we want to return 0 if the first version is equal or later than the second
version_compare(){
  local -a first second

  # Let's start with trivial cases:
  if [[ $1 = "$2" ]] || [[ $1 = "$2".* ]]; then : "$1 >= $2"; return 0; fi

  IFS=. read -r -a first <<<"$1"
  IFS=. read -r -a second <<<"$2"

  local k
  for k in "${!first[@]}"; do
    local a=${first[$k]} b=${second[$k]}
    : "Evaluating field $k ($a vs $b)"
    if [[ ! $b ]]; then
      # ie. first=1.1.1, second=1.1; though this should have been handled above
      : "$1 >= $2"; return 0;
    fi
    if (( $b > $a )); then
      : "$1 < $2"; return 1;
    fi
  done

  : "$1 >= $2"; return 0;
}
compare() {
  version_compare "$2" "$1" # reverse sort order
}
```

To do the file IO, assuming bash 4:

```
readarray -t versions <STRINGS.txt
quicksort versions 0 "$(( ${#versions[@]} - 1 ))"
printf '%s\n' "${versions[@]}"
```

Comment: Thank you! 'sort -V -r' was the solution I was looking for. With "only bash" I  mean without extra software like Python.

Comment: To be a bit contrary, GNU `sort` (as opposed to POSIX sort) is as much extra software as Python is; it's certainly not guaranteed to be available everywhere bash is installed. But I'm glad this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know you don't want Python solution, but for those who lack GNU `sort` (such as OS X) it sure is an easy way to do this.

Given:

```
$ echo "$a"
3.0.3
3.0.11.2
3.0.11.1
3.0.11
3.0.16
3.0.15.1
3.0.15
3.0.14
3.0.10.3
3.0.10.2
3.0.10.1
3.0.13.1
3.0.10
3.0.13
3.0.9
3.0.12
3.0.8
3.0.7.2
3.0.7.1
3.0.7
3.0.9.2
3.0.9.1
3.0.2
3.0.8.1
3.0.6.1
3.0.6
3.0.5
3.0.1
3.0.0
```

Python 1 liner:

```
$ echo "$a" | python -c '
import sys, re; print "".join(sorted(sys.stdin.readlines(), key=lambda s: map(int, re.findall("\\d+", s)), reverse=True))'
3.0.16
3.0.15.1
3.0.15
3.0.14
3.0.13.1
3.0.13
3.0.12
3.0.11.2
3.0.11.1
3.0.11
3.0.10.3
3.0.10.2
3.0.10.1
3.0.10
3.0.9.2
3.0.9.1
3.0.9
3.0.8.1
3.0.8
3.0.7.2
3.0.7.1
3.0.7
3.0.6.1
3.0.6
3.0.5
3.0.3
3.0.2
3.0.1
3.0.0
```